# Enrutar llamada en Asterisk hacia un AGI

Tags: asterisk

Tengo este codigo que debe enviarme al siguiente agi despues de presionar el boton 1, pero no funciona, como puedo resolverlo?

```
exten => 8000,1,Answer
exten => 8000,n,Agi(OpcionesPrincipales.php)
exten => 8000,1,GotoIf($["${OPCIONPRINCIPALSELECCIONADA}" == "1"]?opcion1)
exten => 8000,n(opcion1),AGI(opcion1.php)
exten => 8000,n,Agi(picotts.agi, ${CPFMESSAGE}, es-ES)
exten => 8000,n,Hangup
```

esto es lo que me aparece en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, tu problema en el orden de las prioridades de la regla. Debes cambiar dejando:

```
exten => 8000,1,Answer
exten => 8000,n,Agi(OpcionesPrincipales.php)
exten => 8000,n,GotoIf($["${OPCIONPRINCIPALSELECCIONADA}"="1"]?opcion1) ; <-- la prioridad 1 cambiala por n
exten => 8000,n(opcion1),AGI(opcion1.php)
exten => 8000,n,Agi(picotts.agi, ${CPFMESSAGE}, es-ES)
exten => 8000,n,Hangup
```

Ya que ves en tu imagen de debug, la próxima prioridad que se ejecuta es la 3, esto es:

1. Hace el answer
2. Ejecuta el AGI OpcionesPrincipales.php
3. Ejecuta el AGI opcion1.php
4. Cuelga (hangup)

Así se esté compilando tu regla ya que la linea

```
exten => 8000,1,GotoIf($["${OPCIONPRINCIPALSELECCIONADA}" == "1"]?opcion1)
```

no se toma en cuenta pues ya existe una prioridad 1, y adicional el comparador `=` esta doble y debe ser solo uno.

Con el cambio que indico, debería de contemplarse el GotoIf, el comparador ponlo junto a la comparativa de cadenas, ya que ocasiones no funciona correctamente.

Espero te sirva. Saludos